# Not able to go to the code search while scraping github

Tags: java, selenium, github, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get simulate the online github search using selenium web scraping. I am not able to get the program search in the Code part. Instead it tries to search in the repositories.

Below is the code.

```
FirefoxProfile p = new FirefoxProfile();
    p.setPreference("javascript.enabled", false);


    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    driver.get("https://github.com"); 

    WebElement element;

       element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));



    element.sendKeys("hasRole()");

    element.submit();
    wait(driver);


   element =  driver.findElement(By.name("Code"));  //prev working line


    element.click();
    wait(driver);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the link by *partial link text*:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Code"));
```

Or, *by xpath*, checking the `type=Code` part in the url:

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'type=Code')]"));
```

---

Also, you would probably need to *wait for the element to become visible*:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'type=Code')]")));
```

Comment: Neither of them worked. I tried doing both element.submit();
        element.click(); after using partial link and xpath. But didnt work :(

Comment: Nope. I was also assuming that I should wait for sometime..But then it didn't work... I tried the below as well.
        element =  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'type=Code')]")));
        
        element.click();
        
        
        
        wait(driver);

Comment: @Zack what is that symbol inside the xpath expression - recheck the correctness of the xpath.

Comment: Actually I am not able to decode the xpath except for href and type. What is "//a" for?

Comment: Hey @alecxe..It worked. I was getting some error in the custom wait function and hence it did not proceed further to click on the code part...I found the error in the console.debugged it and then it worked...Thanks :)